# rpm --addsign complains about "no secret key"

Tags: rpm, signature

Running this command I get an error.

```
$ rpm --addsign ./kalzium-libs-19.12.3-1.fc33.i686.rpm 
Enter pass phrase: 
gpg: skipped "Evan Carroll": No secret key
gpg: signing failed: No secret key
Pass phrase check failed or gpg key expired
```

What does it mean to have *No secret key*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problem was the secret keys were created with a different Unix user then the daemon that needed them. I verified this by running,

```
gpg --list-keys
```

You have to dump the secret key, add it to the user you desire and then delete the dumps. These instructions helped me tremendously.

https://askubuntu.com/a/32488/29097

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked for me!